# Spark executers ideals after groupby operator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are working in Spark streaming .
Our DataFrame contains the following columns

[unitID,source,avrobyte,schemeType]

The unitID values are [ 10, 76, 510, 269 , 7, 0, 508, , 509 ,511 , 507]

We active the following command :

```
val dfGrouped :KeyValueGroupedDataset [Int,Car] = dfSource.groupByKey(car1=> ca1.unitID)

val afterLogic : DataSet[CarLogic]= dfGrouped.flatMapGroups{
case(unitID: Int , messages:Iterator[Car])=> performeLogic(...)
}
```

We allocate 8 Spark executers .

In our Dataset we have 10 different units so we have 10 different unitID,
so we excepted that job processing will split on all over the executers in equal manner, but when we looking on the executers performance via the UI I see that only 2  executers are working and all the other are idle during the mission....

What are we doing wrong? or how we can divide the job over all the executers to be more or the less equal...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing can be explained by the low cardinality of your key space. Spark uses a [`HashPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L112) (by default) to assign keys to partitions (by default 200 partitions). On a low cardinality key space this is rather problematic and requires careful attention as each collision has a massive impact. Even further, these partitions then have to be assigned to executors. At the end of this process it's not surprising to end up with a rather sub-optimal distribution of data.

You have a few options:

- If applicable, attempt to increase the cardinality of your keys, e.g. by salting them (appending some randomness temporarily). That has the advantage that you can also better handle skew in the data (when the amount of data per keys is not equally distributed). In a following step you can then remove the random part again and combine the partial results.
- If you absolutely require a partition per key (and the key space is static and well-known), you should configure `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to match the cardinality `n` of your keys space and assign each key a partition id in [0, n) ahead of time (to avoid collisions when hashing). Then you can use this partition id in your `groupBy`.
- Just for completeness, using the `RDD` API you could provide you own custom partitioner that does the same as described above: `rdd.partitionBy(n, customPartitioner)`

Though, one final word: Even following one of the latter two options above, using 8 executors for 10 keys (equals 10 non-empty partitions) is a poor choice. If your data is equally distributed, you will still end up with 2 executors doing double the work. If your data is skewed things might even be worse (or you are accidentally lucky) - in any case, it's out of your control.
So it's best to make sure that the number of partitions can be equally distributed among your executors.